# Android, Instagram unfollow user can't be done?

Tags: android, instagram

I'm working on an Instagram integration app. I want to unfollow a user but i get irrelevant answer from Instagram including html doctype saying "sorry, this page isn't available". I've mentioned relationship permission in my access token url. Does it need the review process? Here is my code:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{                        
                    String urlFollowUnFollow = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"
                    + username
                    + "/relationship?access_token="
                    + GetStats.ACCESS_TOKEN;
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "unfollow"));


                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlFollowUnFollow);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    response = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + response + "  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                }  catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }}
        ).start();
```

By the way, I've seen other stackoverflow posts. none helped. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my client had no access to relationships permission. to gain those access i had to submit my app to a review by Instagram.